# ST_Reclass strange behaviour in PostGIS

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, reclassify

I am applying `st_reclass` to my PostGIS raster table (band 4 ) to

1. replace all `sel_value` where `0 < sel_value < 100` to 1
2. replace all zeros with no data value which in my case is `255`

My code is below

```
SELECT
    ST_Reclass(rast,
    4,
    '[0-0]:255, (0-100):1',
    '8BUI',
    255)
FROM
    myschema.myraster
```

However, I don't think the above code does what it's supposed to be doing. I checked the summary statistics before and after `reclass`

**Before**

```
SELECT
    ST_Summarystats(rast,
    4,
    TRUE)
FROM
    myschema.myraster
```

[image]

**After**

```
SELECT
    ST_Summarystats(ST_Reclass(rast,
    4,
    '[0-0]:255, (0-100):1',
    '8BUI',
    255),
    4,
    TRUE)
FROM
    myschema.myraster
```

[image]

**Observation**

1. Cell count is less than before - **Expected**, I reclassified zeros
   to na values
2. All minimums have been changed from 0 to 1 - **Expected**, I
   replaced any value that are less than 1 to 1
3. All maximums have been changed to 1 - **Unexpected**, I didn't replace any value above 100, so if the previous maximam was > 100, it should be the same now.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `ST_Summarystats` ignore `nodata`, so I'm not surprised the cell count is lower if you change data to nodata.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by "values less than 1": you replace 0 by 255, and 1 and above (you have unsigned int so `(0-100)` should be equivalent to `[1-99]`) by 1, so you should not have any data below 1 in your result
3. Using the reclassarg `[0-0]:255, (0-100):1` will put `0` to `nodata` and `(0-100)` to `255`, but because you don't specify what to do with the rest, I'm not sure but I suspect it will put the rest to `nodata` as well.

If you want to keep the rest without changing it, you can try to just keep the same range for those values: `[0-0]:255, (0-100):1, [100-254]:100-254`